# Automatically copy data into a master sheet from multiple sheets in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched the topics for an answer to the following and have found several variations but not quite exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm brand new to VBA so please excuse my complete lack of knowledge and thank you in advance for any help provided.

What I have is an excel spreadsheet that consists of 7 tabs. 6 tabs that have data added to them on a daily basis and a master tab which I am currently having to copy and paste the daily updates to.

So what I am in need of is the ability to type new data into the 6 data capture tabs and for them to automatically pull through onto the next available row on the master tab.
They all have the same column headings and it would need to be a continuous method as there will be hundreds of data entries over the year.

Headings are from cell A1 to AX1 so the first row would need to be from B2 to AX2 and so on.

Can anyone help with a code that would do this for me?

Thank you

P

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a "code for me site", "teach me to code", or "point me to the right code" site.  It is a place for those with existing code that is not working to get help fixing those problems.  Please past any code attempts in your original post with specific question pertaining to the problem in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and Sorry. Like I said I have no knowledge of VBA at the moment and didn't realise the purpose of the site. will be trying to teach myself. I'll just leave it for now until I manage to learn how to do the coding. Again, thank you.

Comment: One hint is to use the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event.